# FluentIterable: should limit() be called as soon as possible?

Tags: java, guava, iterable

I am looking at the javadoc for Guava's FluentIterable and the gazillion examples on the web, and they tend to put limit() after filter() and transform(), which suggests that all elements are transformed before the Iterable is truncated to the first N. This is the example from their page.

```
   List<String> results =
   FluentIterable.from(database.getClientList())
       .filter(activeInLastMonthPredicate)
       .transform(Functions.toStringFunction())
       .limit(10)
       .toList();
```

This seems quite inefficient. Am I missing something? Why is this pattern being perpetrated? Shouldn't not be the following?

```
   List<String> results =
   FluentIterable.from(database.getClientList())
       .filter(activeInLastMonthPredicate)
       .limit(10)
       .transform(Functions.toStringFunction())
       .toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

[`FluentIterable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) (and Guava's non-fluent [`Iterables`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) and [`Iterators`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html)) are [lazy](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#iterables), which means that

> Unless otherwise noted, all of the iterables produced in this class are lazy, which means that their iterators only advance the backing iteration when absolutely necessary.

That's maybe better explained in JDK 8's [`Stream` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, **and source elements are consumed only as needed**.

and also in [`Stream#limit(int)` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, truncated to be no longer than maxSize in length.
>
> This is a [**short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

(Emphasis mine.)

Because of that there's no difference where you put `.limit(10)` - in both your examples only at most 10 elements will be consumed. You can check that by changing `Functions.toStringFunction()` to something you can inspect to see it'll be called at most 10 times in each case.

Answer (score 1):

## Not especially

See the following example. You will notice that they produce the exact same output.

```
import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    List<String> oddNumbersAsString;

    System.out.println("limit is after transform");
    oddNumbersAsString = FluentIterable.from(numbers)
        .filter(Main::isOdd)
        .transform(Main::asString)
        .limit(3)
        .toList();
    System.out.println(oddNumbersAsString);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("limit is before transform");
    oddNumbersAsString = FluentIterable.from(numbers)
        .filter(Main::isOdd)
        .limit(3)
        .transform(Main::asString)
        .toList();
    System.out.println(oddNumbersAsString);
    System.out.println();

  }

  static boolean isOdd(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("  calling isOdd(" + i + ")");
    return i % 2 == 1;
  }

  static String asString(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("  calling asString(" + i + ")");
    return "" + i;
  }

}
```

The result is the following:

```
limit is after transform
  calling isOdd(1)
  calling asString(1)
  calling isOdd(2)
  calling isOdd(3)
  calling asString(3)
  calling isOdd(4)
  calling isOdd(5)
  calling asString(5)
[1, 3, 5]

limit is before transform
  calling isOdd(1)
  calling asString(1)
  calling isOdd(2)
  calling isOdd(3)
  calling asString(3)
  calling isOdd(4)
  calling isOdd(5)
  calling asString(5)
[1, 3, 5]
```

### However...

Be careful when using *other* methods, like `skip`, because those will be transformed before being skipped!

Comment: @Xaerxess and you spared me from fetching the doc ;)